# Material UI Pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, pagination

I don't understand why my page can't recognize other pages when I click (for example on page 2, the same page appears again and again)

This is in MealNew.js component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './MealNew.css';
import Card from "../UI/Card";
import AppPagination from "./AppPagination";

const MealNew = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [showData, setShowData] = useState(false);
    const [query,setQuery] = useState('');
    const[page,setPage] = useState(9);
    const[numberOfPages,setNumberOfPages]= useState(10);

    const handleClick = () => {
      setShowData(true);
      const link = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?query=${query}&apiKey=XYZABC&page=${page}`;
      fetch (link)
      .then ((response)=> response.json())
      .then ((data) => {
        setData(data.results)
        setNumberOfPages(data.total_pages)

    const elementFood =  data?.map((meal,key) => {
     return (<div key={key}>
       
       <h1>{meal.title}</h1>
       <img src={meal.image}
       alt='e-meal'/>
     </div> )

})

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  handleClick();
}

useEffect(()=> {
  handleClick();
},[page])


  return (
      <Card className="meal">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input 
       className="search"
       placeholder="Search..."
       value={query}
       onChange={(e)=>setQuery(e.target.value)}/>
       <input type='submit' value='Search'/>

       </form>
      
        <li className="meal">
        <div className = 'meal-text'>
       <h5>{showData && elementFood}</h5>
       <AppPagination
         setPage={setPage}
        pageNumber={numberOfPages}  
              />

        </div>
        </li>
      </Card>
    
       ) }

export default MealNew;
```

This is in AppPagination.js component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Pagination } from "@mui/material";

const AppPagination = ({setPage,pageNumber}) => {
    const handleChange = (page)=> {
        setPage(page)
        window.scroll(0,0)
        console.log (page)

    }
  return (
    <div >
        <div >
        
            <Pagination
            onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e.target.textContent)}
            variant="outlined"
            count={pageNumber}/>
        
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AppPagination;
```

Thanks in advance, I would appreciate it a lot

The only error I am getting in Console is this:
Line 64:3:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleClick'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not following the `spoonacular` api.
Your link looks like this:
`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?query=${query}&apiKey=<API_KEY>&page=${page}`

I checked the spoonacular `Search Recipes Api` and there's no `page` parameter you can pass. You have to used `number` instead of `page`.

When you receive response from the api, it returns the following keys: `offset`, `number`, `results` and `totalResults`.

You are storing `totalResults` as `totalNumberOfPages` in state which is wrong. MUI Pagination count takes total number of pages not the total number of records. You can calculate the total number of pages by:
`Math.ceil(totalRecords / recordsPerPage)`. Let say you want to display 10 records per page and you have total 105 records.

`Total No. of Pages = Math.ceil(105/10)= 11`

Also i pass page as prop to `AppPagination` component to make it as controlled component.

Follow the documentation:

[Search Recipes](https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Search-Recipes-Complex)

[Pagination API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/pagination/)

**Complete Code**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Card, Pagination } from "@mui/material";

const RECORDS_PER_PAGE = 10;

const MealNew = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [showData, setShowData] = useState(false);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [numberOfPages, setNumberOfPages] = useState();

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowData(true);
    const link = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?query=${query}&apiKey=<API_KEY>&number=${page}`;
    fetch(link)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.results);

        const totalPages = Math.ceil(data.totalResults / RECORDS_PER_PAGE);
        setNumberOfPages(totalPages);
      });
  };

  const elementFood = data?.map((meal, key) => {
    return (
      <div key={key}>
        <h1>{meal.title}</h1>
        <img src={meal.image} alt='e-meal' />
      </div>
    );
  });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleClick();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleClick();
    console.log("first");
  }, [page]);

  return (
    <Card className='meal'>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input className='search' placeholder='Search...' value={query} onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
        <input type='submit' value='Search' />
      </form>

      <li className='meal'>
        <div className='meal-text'>
          <h5>{showData && elementFood}</h5>
          <AppPagination setPage={setPage} pageNumber={numberOfPages} page={page} />
        </div>
      </li>
    </Card>
  );
};

const AppPagination = ({ setPage, pageNumber, page }) => {
  const handleChange = (page) => {
    setPage(page);
    window.scroll(0, 0);
    console.log(page);
  };

  console.log("numberOfPages", pageNumber);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Pagination
          page={page}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.textContent)}
          variant='outlined'
          count={pageNumber}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MealNew;
```

Comment: It's close to the answer. First when i search (for example) pasta, i only get 1 result, but if i click on page 4 i will get the same first result and 3 others (if I click on page 9, it will get the same first 3 results and 6 others)

Comment: There's one more parameter `offset` that basically skip the number of records. Suppose if you are on page 2 and the limit is 15 then you want to skip first 15 records. You can use this formula to calculate offset `(page -1 * limit)`. 
I'm not sure but may be you don't need to provide the `number` parameter.

Comment: Do you have instagram or facebook so I can ask you about details. I would really appreciate it a lot. I started learning like 4 months ago